# Python opts get empty values

Tags: python

I'm trying to work with opts but cannot get it to work in other PC because arguments it's always empty. Below is my code.

```
import getopt
import sys

try:
    print getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "f::c::")
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "f::c::")
except getopt.GetoptError, err:
    # print help information and exit:
    print str(err) # will print something like "option -a not recognized"
    sys.exit(2)

print opts
print args

funcion = None
tipo = None

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-f'):
        funcion = arg
    if opt in ('-c'):
        tipo = arg

print funcion
print tipo
```

**usage test:**

```
python test.py –f import_dbs –c 1
```

**PC A result:**

```
([('-f', 'imports'), ('-c', '1')], [])
[('-f', 'imports'), ('-c', '1')]
[]
imports
1
```

**PC B result:**

```
([], ['\x96f', 'import_dbs', '\x96c', '1'])
[]
['\x96f', 'import_dbs', '\x96c', '1']
None
None
```

Comment: What are "PC A" and "PC B"?

Comment: PC B. is showing the unicode dashes instead of simple hyphens of PC A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your cli command, not your code.  you have dashes (or some sort of unicode) instead of hyphens

```
$ python test.py –f import_dbs –c 1
None
None
$ python test.py -f import_dbs –c 1
import_dbs
None
$ python test.py -f import_dbs -c 1
import_dbs
1
$ echo "python test.py –f import_dbs –c 1" | od -c
0000000    p   y   t   h   o   n       t   e   s   t   .   p   y       –
0000020   **  **   f       i   m   p   o   r   t   _   d   b   s       –
0000040   **  **   c       1  \n                                        
0000046
$ echo "python test.py -f import_dbs -c 1" | od -c
0000000    p   y   t   h   o   n       t   e   s   t   .   p   y       -
0000020    f       i   m   p   o   r   t   _   d   b   s       -   c    
0000040    1  \n                                                        
0000042
```

probably caused by cutting and pasting or weird keyboard mapping.

Comment: Thanks! i'm using ConEmu console, i test with windows cmd and it's works!

Comment: Good.  If it was helpful, feel free to mark my answer as correct.